# Pass ID results to an IF statement

Tags: javascript, html

The ability to swipe between images (works fine:

```
    <div id='mySwipe' style='width:720px; height:981px; margin-top:55px;' class='swipe'>
      <div class='swipe-wrap'>
        <div><a id="cast1" onClick="change('cast1'); return false" href="#"><img src="../slider/alexis-slider.png" /></a></div>
        <div><a id="cast2" onClick="change('cast2'); return false" href="#"><img src="../slider/joanna-slider.png" /></a></div>
        <div><a id="cast3" onClick="change('cast3'); return false" href="#"><img src="../slider/adriana-slider.png" /></a></div>
        <div><a id="cast4" onClick="change('cast4'); return false" href="#"><img src="../slider/melissa-slider.png" /></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script>
// pure JS
    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
    });
</script>
```

This following code takes the cast# id and gives it a specific class to it, so it knows which image to display (image is identified in CSS).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript/1.2">
    function change(v) {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");

         if (v == "cast1") {target.className = "imgA";} 
    else if (v == "cast2") {target.className = "imgB";} 
    else if (v == "cast3") {target.className = "imgC";} 
    else if (v == "cast4") {target.className = "imgD";} 

    else {target.className = "bio";}
}

function changeReset() {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    target.className = "bio";
}

// pure JS
    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
    });
</script>
```

These both code snippets work fine individually, but I can't figure out how to pass the id results from the swipe code (cast1, 2,3 or 4)to the if statement.  Can someone please help me, I have been working on this for almost 2 weeks now.  I think it's simple, but I am not that good with javascript.

Here is the css:

```
.swipe {overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; position: relative;}
.swipe-wrap {overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
.swipe-wrap > div {float:left; width:100%; position: relative;}
#mySwipe div b {display:block; margin:0px; margin-top:240px; background:url(""); height:1280px; width:720px;}
#inner {background: url("../bio_footer/alexis-bio.png") no-repeat 0 0; height:440px; width:800px;}
#target {background: url("") no-repeat 0 0; height:440px; width:800px;}
.bio {height:440px; width:800px;}
.imgA{background: url("../bio_footer/alexis-bio.png") no-repeat 0 0; height:440px; width:800px;} 
.imgB{background: url("../bio_footer/joanna-bio.png") no-repeat 0 0; height:440px; width:800px;} 
.imgC{background: url("../bio_footer/adriana-bio.png") no-repeat 0 0; height:440px; width:800px;} 
.imgD{background: url("../bio_footer/melissa-bio.png") no-repeat 0 0; height:440px; width:800px;}

.container {bottom:106px ;display:none ;position:absolute;}
```

Comment: I don't know why everybody seems to use jQuery tag for their js question...

Comment: Maybe with `change(this)` on your `onClick`? - `onClick="change(this);`

Comment: @A.Wolff He also used the css tag when there's no styling in his question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You already are passing the ID to `change()` and using it in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks.

I just needed to understand what the code was doing more than what I was expecting it to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the callback method of the swype.
[Watch here for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8QNW/)

```
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
  // startSlide: 4,
  auto: 3000,
  callback: function(index, element) {
  var required_id = $(element).attr('id');
  alert(required_id);
   },

});
```

Comment: @sudhAsu63 Thanks for the example, you have each slide numbered.  what if you wanted to add an onclick effect to each slide associated with each number?  That what I am trying to accomplish.